# How to concatenate database elements to a string

Tags: python, database, concatenation

I'm currently trying to take elements from a database to be displayed in a string by iterating through each row and adding it to an empty string.

```
    def PrintOverdueBooks():
        printed_message = ""
        for row in db_actions.GetAllOverdue():
            printed_message += row
            printed_message += " \n"
        print(printed_message)
```

Whenever the function is called I receive an error stating that "row" is a tuple and cannot be concatenated to a string. Using **.join** also creates an error.

Comment: How did you try to use `.join`?

Comment: What’s the expected result exactly?

Comment: @deceze I used 
```
printed_message.join(row) 
```
when trying the .join command. The expected result is to have each row in the database be printed on a separate line (but still part of the same string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def PrintOverdueBooks():
        printed_message = ''
        for row in db_actions.GetAllOverdue():
            stup = ''.join(row)
            printed_message += stup
        print(printed_message)
```

Comment: Check the edited code, you need to convert tuple to string first